# Podcast Apps Syncing Account

Tags: data-synchronization, icloud, podcasts.app

As you know, Apple's own podcast app started syncing podcast subscriptions and their metadata through the air. But it seems that the app automatically uses the Apple account designated for store purchases; not the user's personal iCloud account.

Since in my family we've a general store account and a single iCloud account per user, this situation makes syncing podcast behave bad since all of us listen different ones.

So, do any of you know a workaround about how I can change the podcast app's syncing account from the store account to the user's personal iCloud account? Or is it an Apple limitation at the moment?

Thanks.

Comment: Ever found a solution for that ?

Comment: @nojetlag unfortunately no